# Git diff between master and all files changed in a pull request

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have two branches: `master` and `my_branch`. 
While working on `my_branch`, I made changes to N files file1.cpp, file2.cpp ... fileN.cpp and created a pull request. Note that my changes span multiple commits (for ex:, I changed file1.cpp to file3.cpp in first commit and rest N-3 files in next commit). Meanwhile, Alice, Bob and Charlie, also push their changes to master including some that touch those N files. I, then do a git pull (while on `master`) to get the latest master from remote repo. Now, I want to view exactly which files are different in `my_branch` and `master`. Note that I only care about the N files in `my_branch` that I made changes/commits to (visible in Files changed section in my pull request). I don't care about the thousand other files that might have been changed by others. One way to do this would be:

```
git diff master my_branch file1.cpp
git diff master my_branch file2.cpp
...
git diff master my_branch fileN.cpp
```

Is there a better way to do this, instead of manually typing diff for each file?

Note that:

```
git diff master my_branch
```

is not helpful since it lists a thousand other files apart from the N files I actually made changes to.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have any characters requiring quoting (white space, etc.), you can do:

```
git diff master mybranch -- $(git diff --name-only master...mybranch)
```

If you do have files which require quoting then you will have to fall back to something like:

```
git diff -z --name-only master...mybranch | xargs -0 git diff master mybranch --
```

Answer (score 0):

Merge the `master` branch into yours, then diff the two branches.